# How to change launcher icon path of an installed application

Tags: launcher, paths

I have installed pyCharm in mu ubuntu machine, I use the kde enviroment. The application folder was at `/home/userName/pyCharm` and the application icon was pointing at `/home/userName/pyCharm/bin/pycharm.sh` to launch the application. Now when I moved the `pyCharm` folder to another location and try to open the application from the launcer icon I get the error `Could not find the program '/home/mrme/pycharm-2017.1.2/bin/pycharm.sh'`. How can I reset the path of the laucher icon to point at the new path?

Comment: Run `locate .desktop | grep pycharm`, open the found `pycharm.desktop` and edit the `Exec=<...>` line with the new absolute path to the pycharm.sh executable.

Comment: Did it work? I'd like to know if I an improve my answer :)

Comment: Yes, it worked for all the applications I changed the path. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Run `locate .desktop | grep pycharm`
2. Open the found `pycharm.desktop` such as `gksudo gedit /path/to/.desktop`
3. Edit the `Exec=<...>` line with the new **absolute path** to the `pycharm.sh` executable and save the changes.

Comment: You can also change the icon path in the same file so you can see the icon at the launcher